# In Swift3, combine responds#to and calling in one fell swoop?

Tags: swift, respondstoselector

For example,

```
superview?.subviews.filter{
    $0 != self &&
    $0.responds(to: #selector(setter: Blueable.blue))
  }.map{
    ($0 as! Blueable).blue = false
  }
```

Is there a concept like ..

```
x.blue??? = false
```

'???' meaning 'if it responds to blue, call blue'...

Note - I fully appreciate I could write an extension, `callIfResponds:to`, or a specific extension, `blueIfBlueable`.

I'm wondering if there's some native swiftyness here, which I don't know about. It seems to be a pretty basic concept.

---

Footnote:

in the ensuing heated discussion, there is mention of **using a protocol**. Just for the benefit of anyone reading, here's one approach to using a protocol:

```
protocol Blueable:class {
    var blue:Bool { get set }
}

extension Blueable where Self:UIView {
    func unblueAllSiblings() { // make this the only blued item
        superview?.subviews.filter{$0 != self}
            .flatMap{$0 as? Blueable}
            .forEach{$0.blue = false}
    }
}

// explanation: anything "blueable" must have a blue on/off concept.
// you get 'unblueAllSiblings' for free, which you can call from
// any blueable item to unblue all siblings (likely, if that one just became blue)
```

To use it, for example...

```
@IBDesignable
class UILabelStarred: UILabel, Blueable {

    var blueStar: UIView? = nil
    let height:CGFloat = 40
    let shinyness:CGFloat = 0.72
    let shader:Shader = Shaders.Glossy
    let s:TimeInterval = 0.35

    @IBInspectable var blue:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if (blue == true) { unblueAllSiblings() }
            blueize()
        }
    }

    func blueize() {

        if (blueStar == nil) {
            blueStar = UIView()
            self.addSubview(blueStar!)
            ... draw, say, a blue star here
            }
        if (blue) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: s) {
                self. blueStar!.backgroundColor = corporateBlue03
                self.textColor = corporateBlue03
            }
        }
        else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: s) {
                self. blueStar!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                self.textColor = sfBlack5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just going back to the original question, that's all fine. But you can't "pick up on" an existing property (a simple example is `isHidden`) in existing classes.

Furthermore as long as we're discussing it, note that in that example protocol extension, you unfortunately can NOT have the protocol or extension automatically, as it were, call unblueAllSiblings from "inside" the protocol or extension, for exactly this reason: [why you can't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863469/swift-property-observer-in-protocol-extension)

Comment: @appzYourLife I don't really think the [functional-programming] tag is appropriate here given that OP is using side-effects, and functional programming is about avoiding side-effects.

Comment: @Hamish Ok agreed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I think what you want is:

```
superview?.subviews.filter {
   $0 != self // filter out self
}.flatMap {
  $0 as? Blueable
}.forEach {
  $0.blue = false
}
```

Why should you be checking whether a class conforms to a setter when you can check the type?

Checking selectors should not be used in pure Swift. You will need it mostly for interacting with Obj-C APIs - dynamic methods, optional methods in protocols or informal protocols.

Comment: Hmm, thanks x100000 for the answer; however *"Why should you be checking whether a class conforms to a setter when you can check the type?"* - how bizarre man; surely you can instantly see in the example that one could have any number of custom controls where you want to deblue?  "Turning off all my siblings where I get turned on" is step one in, well, making UX you know?!

Comment: @JoeBlow The funny thing is that you are checking if there is a setter for property `blue` and then you are force casting to `Blueable` instead of the obvious `is Blueable`. That's the whole point of the *protocol* there.

Comment: @JoeBlow, wouldn't `Blueable` be a protocol that you'd make all of your custom controls adopt if they have the `blue` `Bool` property?  `protocol Blueable: class {
    var blue: Bool { get set }
}`

Comment: hey @vacawama - by all means, you could use a protocol here. Note that you still have to check (/cast, something) the protocol.

Comment: @JoeBlow, true.  My point is that the protocol would allow *any number of custom controls* to work with all of these answers.

Comment: hey @vacawama sure, but if you check to see if it responds, you can use it with any number of custom controls.  consider `isHidden`, you may be using existing apple stuff that is isHiddenAble, or your own stuff. Note that, if, as Sulthan says, "Checking selectors should not be used in Swift" and that's just an idiomatic rule about Swift - then, sure.  What more can you say? "Checking selectors should not be used in Swift" and that's that.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, a better way of going about this is by conditionally type-casting rather than using `responds(to:)`. However, don't overlook just using a `for in` loop – they're pretty powerful, allowing you to use pattern matching and `where` clauses, allowing you to iterate over a given subset of elements.

```
for case let blueable as Blueable in superview?.subviews ?? [] where blueable !== self {
    blueable.blue = false
}
```

- `case let blueable as Blueable` uses the [type-casting pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID425) in order to only match elements that are `Blueable`, and bind them to `blueable` if successful.
- `where blueable !== self` excludes `self` from being matched.

Comment: You know you've hit the nail on the head here.  The "super powerful for loops" in Swift is an area that many engineers - certainly me - don't know enough about or don't use enough.  Good call.

Comment: can you use the "type-casting pattern", sort of "once in one line of code for one variable" ... ?  So, as I ask "x.blue??? = false" the answer would be something like ...... `(case x as Blueable)?.blue = false` ......... maybe?!?

Comment: @JoeBlow No you cannot use it inline, only in a pattern matching context such as an `if case` or `for case`, but as others have mentioned, `(x as? Blueable)?.blue = false` is a simple way to do it inline through the use of the conditional type-casting operator `as?` and optional chaining.

Comment: Got it - that's a shame really!  Yes, understood that `(x as? Blueable)?.blue = false` is excellent.  In a sense, my question was is there a "similar form" to that, specifically asking about responds.  So, you can imagine something like `(x as? (.blue) )?.blue = false` or you can imagine something like `(x as? (#selector(blah)) )?.blah(42)`.  Anyways I guess the answer is "no" - thanks!!

Comment: I think a basic tension here is, as Sulth. mentions since swift is protocol-oriented, you "shouldn't use" responds#to in Swift.  But the responds#to call exists.  And you can trivially give good uses cases.  So ... the concept "shouldn't use" is often troubled.

Comment: @JoeBlow It's not so much that you shouldn't *ever* use `responds(to:)` in Swift, there are valid use cases for it (mainly for things like introspection, which the Obj-C runtime is great at, and Swift less so). However its use here is clunky and awkward because saying `x.responds(to: #selector(setter: Blueable.blue))` doesn't tell the compiler that `x` has a static type with the property `blue` – you have to force cast in order to achieve that (which is actually risky, because having the property `blue` doesn't automatically mean it's a `Blueable`).

Comment: That's why using protocols and conditional type-casting is the preferred approach, as it is safe, concise and flexible.

Comment: Hmm, understood, but what about if you're "adding one" .. so, a lot of apple's stuff responds to isHidden, and I'd make new things that (are completely conceptually unrelated, but) also respond to isHidden?  Does that "feel" like responds#to to you, @hamish??

Comment: @JoeBlow Not really, you could create a `Hideable` protocol with an `isHidden` property requirement and then extend `UIView` to conform to it, along with any other things that you create that have an `isHidden` property :)

Comment: Hmm - you perfectly present the "totally Swift" outlook!  Good one. In any event, as I say nice one on presenting the "super powerful for loops" approach.

Answer (score 2):

Why not check conformance to the type directly? Something like:

```
superview?.subviews.forEach {
    guard $0 !== self else { return }
    ($0 as? Blueable)?.blue = false
}
```

Comment: just BTW wouldn't that be `continue` rather than `return`

Comment: No, unlike a for loop (in which case it would be `continue`), `.forEach` is a function that takes in a closure that works on each iterated element. The `{...}` block after `forEach` represent a closure and not a scoped `for` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this extension

```
extension UIView {
    var siblings: [UIView] { return self.superview?.subviews.filter { $0 != self } ?? [] }
}
```

Now pick the solution that you prefer among the followings

### Solution 1

```
siblings.flatMap { $0 as? Blueable }.forEach { $0.blue = false  }
```

### Solution 2

```
siblings.forEach { ($0 as? Blueable)?.blue = false }
```

Comment: I had exactly the same thought about `siblings` but I would then probably combine it with `for case let blueable as Blueable in siblings`.

Comment: @Sulthan The `for case let...` is very very nice.

Comment: I couldn't remember the correct syntax but Hamish already added it as his answer.

Comment: @Sulthan Anyway the syntax you did write in your comment `for case let blueable as Blueable in siblings` was correct.

Comment: hi @appzYourLife.  I would direct you to the part of my question that says **Note - I fully appreciate I could write an extension**...   :)

Comment: @JoeBlow: You are are right :D I've read that part too late. If you want I can remove my answer.